# Mongodb Backend for Node ACL Always Returning False

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I am currently trying to implement the Node ACL Module found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl in a Mean.JS (v0.4.2) application.

By default, Mean.JS uses the 'memoryBackend' which works fine for most things, however I'd like to make the user roles / permissions dynamically settable from the browser.

I am getting a list of ACL definitions in the database, which *appear* to be correct, but when trying to read back permissions

I first include the 'acl' module in my application, open a connection to the database, and define my roles/access.

```
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl 
    var acl = require('acl');

    var ACL_PREFIX = 'acl_';
    var _ACL = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, ACL_PREFIX));

    // Some Sample ACL Definitions
    var default_acl = [
        {
            role: 'technician',
            resources: ['workorders'],
            permissions: ['view']
        },
        {
            role: 'sales',
            resources: ['workorders'],
            permissions: ['add', 'edit', 'view', 'delete'],
        },
        {
            role: 'superadmin',
            resources: ['workorders'],
            permissions: ['*']
        }
    ];
```

I add these now by iterating over the different ACL items. (I've also tried adding them all at once)

```
    // Iterate Over each ACL Entry, I've also tried adding them all at once, eg: _ACL.allow(default_acl)
    async.forEachSeries(default_acl, function (aclEntry, nextEntry) {

        console.log("Giving the '%s' role access to %s [%s]",
            aclEntry.role, aclEntry.resources.join(', '), aclEntry.permissions.join(', ')
        );

        // Next Entry is the Callback to next item in the default_acl list.
        _ACL.allow(aclEntry.role, aclEntry.resources, aclEntry.permissions, nextEntry)

    }, function (doneDefiningACL) {

        async.forEachSeries(['technician', 'sales', 'superadmin'], function (currentRole, nextRole) {

            // Check Each role with 'allowedPermissions'
            _ACL.allowedPermissions(currentRole, 'workorders', function (err, permissions) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("ERROR: %s", err);
                }

                console.log("\n-> Current Role: %s \n-> Permissions: %s\n",
                    currentRole, util.inspect(permissions)
                );

                async.forEachSeries(['add', 'edit', 'view', 'delete'], function (action, nextAction) {

                    // Check Each Role with '.isAllowed'
                    _ACL.isAllowed(currentRole, 'workorders', action, function (err, canAccess) {
                        console.log("--> %s can '%s' workorders: %s", currentRole, action, util.inspect(canAccess));

                        nextAction();
                    });


                }, function (doneCheckingAllActions) {
                    nextRole();
                });
            });


        }, function (doneAllRoles) {
            console.log("\n\nDone Generating ACL");
        });
    });
```

This produces the following output when run:

```
    Giving the 'technician' role access to workorders [view]
    Giving the 'sales' role access to workorders [add, edit, view, delete]
    Giving the 'superadmin' role access to workorders [*]

    -> Current Role: technician
    -> Permissions: { workorders: [] }

    --> technician can 'add' workorders: false
    --> technician can 'edit' workorders: false
    --> technician can 'view' workorders: false
    --> technician can 'delete' workorders: false

    -> Current Role: sales
    -> Permissions: { workorders: [] }

    --> sales can 'add' workorders: false
    --> sales can 'edit' workorders: false
    --> sales can 'view' workorders: false
    --> sales can 'delete' workorders: false

    -> Current Role: superadmin
    -> Permissions: { workorders: [] }

    --> superadmin can 'add' workorders: false
    --> superadmin can 'edit' workorders: false
    --> superadmin can 'view' workorders: false
    --> superadmin can 'delete' workorders: false


    Done Generating ACL
```

If I go and take a look at the MongoDB database, I can see I have 3 collections that have been generated:

```
    // acl_meta collection:
    > db.acl_meta.find();
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e2"), "key" : "roles", "technician" : true, "sales" : true, "superadmin" : true }

    // acl_resources collection:
    > db.acl_resources.find();
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e4"), "key" : "technician", "workorders" : true }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e6"), "key" : "sales", "workorders" : true }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e8"), "key" : "superadmin", "workorders" : true }

    // acl_allows_workorders collection:
    > db.acl_allows_workorders.find();
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e3"), "key" : "technician", "view" : true }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e5"), "key" : "sales", "add" : true, "edit" : true, "view" : true, "delete" : true }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57bdc84df251c5ae69d7c4e7"), "key" : "superadmin", "*" : true }
```

These appear to have been built correctly, but the permissions are still returning false no matter what role, or action is being checked.

**UPDATE**
The .whatResources() function seems to be returning which resources a given role has access to correctly, but why the .isAllowed() and .allowedPermisions() functions are not working is still a mystery.

For example:

```
    console.log("\n\nChecking What Resources Each Role Has Access To...");

    async.forEachSeries(['technician', 'sales', 'superadmin'], function (currentRole, nextRole) {

        _ACL.whatResources(currentRole, function (err, resources) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("ERROR: %s", err);
            } else {
                console.log("\n-> %s's Have Access to The Following Resources: \n%s", currentRole, util.inspect(resources) ); 

                nextRole();
            }

        });


    }, function (doneCheckingWhatPermissionsEachRoleHas) {
        console.log("\n\nDone Testing ACL");
    });
```

Will print the following output:

```
    Checking What Resources Each Role Has Access To...

    -> technician's Have Access to The Following Resources:
    { workorders: [ 'view' ] }

    -> sales's Have Access to The Following Resources:
    { workorders: [ 'add', 'edit', 'view', 'delete' ] }

    -> superadmin's Have Access to The Following Resources:
    { workorders: [ '*' ] }


    Done Testing ACL
```

I'd like to get this working using 'isAllowed' and 'allowedPermissions', as to change this over to use 'whatResources' would require refactoring all of the ACL policy configurations from the original 'memoryBackend' implementation in MeanJS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your code i don't see you use function addUserRoles(userId, roleId, function(err)). Maybe it's cause return false. I have been same, you can read [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl#addUserRoles)

Hope help you.